# Virtual Path Issue

Tags: c#

Hello Code Experts,
I am uploading some files to a virtual directory. For the virtual directory I am giving the path like

```
"/Uploads/" + DatabaseName + "/" + REOID + "/" + "ExternalDocument" + "/";
```

It works fine in my local but not in live server. It is not uploading files in live server.

If I change it to

```
"~/Uploads/" + DatabaseName + "/" + REOID + "/" + "ExternalDocument" + "/";
```

Then will it work? If not then how shall I map it to virtual directory?

Answer (score 2):

use the Server.MapPath function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

```
Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + DatabaseName + "/" + REOID + "/" + "ExternalDocument" + "/");
```

Comment: I tried using this but it is not working in my local now. None the images have got uploaded.

Comment: Is there a specific error that is coming back when you try to upload a file?

Comment: Actually i am using a web-handler file to write the images to the virtual directory which is not getting called when i give like you said but it is getting called when i use like "~/Uploads/" + DatabaseName + "/" + REOID + "/" + "ExternalDocument" + "/";

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation on waht the ~ means. You willfind ou tthe second approach is always valid, the first one not. Te first assuems the folder is /Uploads (at the web server root).

Comment: Thanks for telling me,  will the second approach work on live too ?

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @MarkisT. Would suggest you also let the Framework do the combination for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782933.aspx

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

var path = Path.Combine("~/Uploads", DataBaseName, REOID, "ExternalDocument");
var fullPath = Server.MapPath(path);
```

If you are still having issues; would suggest you inspect fullPath on local and server to understand what is happening as relates to virtual and absolute paths. You may also have security issues on the server, especially if you happen to be writing outside the application directory. Of course, would expect exceptions in that case.

Comment: Iam getting error' No Overload for method 'Combine' takes 4 arguments

Comment: It's in .NET Framework 4+. On 3.5 and below, you would have to use multiple Path.Combine statements (2 arguments each) or combing by hand. The advice about inspecting the result of Server.MapPath still stands - understanding where you are actually writing to is key to solving your problem.